# Pixijs 5.X with fallback not working on NUXT.JS

Tags: nuxt.js, pixi.js

There is a lack of guidance on how to add pixi.js (new versions 5+) on nuxtjs projects, including the possibility to fallback from webgl to canvas if needed.
After doing everything from the documentation found over pixijs and github we had these two situations 
"PIXI not found" - using pixi.js-legacy npm module inserted in nuxt without ssr
"WEBGL not supported" - using pixi.js npm module inserted in nuxt without ssr.

[SOLVED] in answer.

Answer (score 6):

How to add pixi.js 5+ with canvas fallback from webgl in nuxt.js step by step:
If you work with pixi.js v5+ it will only support webgl. They have pixi.js-legacy library that offers canvas fallback also. We'll use that.

- setp 1: install over npm

  `npm i pixi.js-legacy`
- step 2: add a plugin called pixi-projection

  `npm i pixi-projection`
- step 3: **create a file** in your **plugins folder** called pixijs.js and add these lines, then save it

  `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js-legacy';
  global.PIXI = PIXI;
  require("pixi-projection");
  const renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer();`
- step 4: edit your **nuxt.config.js** and add this new created file into the plungins array of objects with ssr option set to false

`..................................
    plugins: [
            ......
            { src: '~/plugins/pixijs', mode: 'client', ssr: false}
            ],
..................................`

- step 5: go to a **new .vue page** and try their example (pixi default). The page should look something like this:

```html
<template>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
      this.startPixi();
  },
  methods: {
    startPixi() {
      const app = new PIXI.Application();
      document.body.appendChild(app.view);
      let img = require('~/assets/ec-newlogo.png'); //ADD YOUR IMAGE
      app.loader.add('bunny', img).load((loader, resources) => {
        const bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(resources.bunny.texture);
        bunny.x = app.renderer.width / 2;
        bunny.y = app.renderer.height / 2;
        bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
        bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;
        app.stage.addChild(bunny);
        app.ticker.add(() => {
          bunny.rotation += 0.01;
        });
      });
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

Cheers from facem.site